# Inserting the first value of a key-value pair, when the value is a list

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, initialization

I have a dictionary as below, where the key is a string and the value is a list of doubles:

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> dataStore = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
List<string> channel_names = new List<string>(); // contains the keys
```

Now when I want to add data to this dictionary, I do:

```
if (dataStore.ContainsKey(channel_names[j]))
{
    dataStore[channel_names[j]].Add(measurement);
}
                            
else
{
    dataStore.Add(channel_names[j], new List<double>((int)measurement));
}
```

The first statement (adding to an existing key) works fine, but something is wrong with the second statement, i.e. when I am trying to initialise the keys with the first double in the list. The first measurement is being missed out. Can anyone please advise as to why?

Thanks

Comment: I thought this was odd too, but if I do not case it throws an error "CS1503: cannot convert from double to int". Not sure why this is since the dictionary is clearly specified double for the list.

Comment: The `List<T>` constructor that takes an `int` uses the integer to set the capacity of the list, it doesn't add it to the list.  What you want (in pseudo-code) is: `if (!ContainsKey()) { CreateNewListAndAddIt();} /*then alway*/ AddMeasurementToAppropriateList();`

Comment: For anyone here concerned about performance of this in a tight loop, you can change `ContainsKey` to `TryGetValue` and save one key lookup

Answer (score 5):

You are using the constructor [`List(int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_), where `int` specifies the *initial capacity* of the list; it does not add that number to the list.

You could instead use [collection-initialiser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) syntax:

```
new List<double> { measurement }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two constructors for `List<T>` that do different things.

When you call new `List<T>(int)` you create a new list of the provided size - or more exact the initial **capacity** of that list.

When you want to create and fill a new list in one go, you should use a [collection-initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

```
dataStore.Add(channel_names[j], new List<double> { measurement });
```

As an asside you can simplify your code:

```
if (!dataStore.ContainsKey(channel_names[j]))
{
    dataStore[channel_names[j]] = new List<int>();
}                                
dataStore[channel_names[j]].Add(measurement);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor your code to this solution:

```
if (!dataStore.ContainsKey(channel_names[j]))
{
    dataStore.Add(channel_names[j], new List<double>());
    
}
dataStore[channel_names[j]].Add(measurement);
```

It will make it clearer that the `measurment` is always added to the list, regardless of the result of the `ContainsKey` method.

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comments and others have mentioned, you aren't adding things to the list when you construct it, you are allocating capacity to the list.  The code you want is:

```
if (!dataStore.ContainsKey(channel_names[j]))
{
    dataStore.Add(channel_names[j], new List<double>();
}
dataStore[channel_names[j]].Add(measurement);
```

If the Dictionary doesn't contain the key you want, you create a new list and add it to the dictionary.  At this point, the dictionary necessarily contains the appropriate key (it either already existed and you skipped the `if` block, or it didn't exist and you created it).  In any case, at that point, you can just add the measurement to the appropriate list.

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternatives:

1. If you have `list` for given key, just add `measurement` to the existing value (which is list)
2. If `dataStore` doesn't have the key, you should add entire key-value pair: key (`channel_names[j]`) and value which is list with one item

Code:

```
if (dataStore.TryGetValue(channel_names[j], out var list))
  // the key exists; just add measurement to the existing list
  list.Add(measurement);
else
  // no key found; add key-value pair: key and a list with one item 
  dataStore.Add(channel_names[j], new List<double>() {measurement});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [constructor on `List<T>` which takes an integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_) is not adding that integer to the list. It is setting the capacity of the list.

Instead you could use an initializer...

`dataStore.Add(channel_names[j], new List<double>() { measurement };`

Alternatively, you could use [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-5.0) to find the `List<double>` for the given `string`, add it if it doesn't exist, then just modify it.

```
List<double> values = null;
if (!dataStore.TryGetValue(channel_names[j], out values))
{
   values = new List<double>();
   dataStore.Add(channel_names[j], values);
}
values.Add(measurement);
```